# Getting 'Address already in use' when I try to bind a socket to localhost in php

Tags: php, sockets, localhost

I'm trying to create a socket connection from a php script to a local server (Qt, QLocalServer) but I'm having trouble just creating a connection on the php side.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');


set_time_limit(0);
ob_implicit_flush();

echo 'usr='. get_current_user().'<br/>';

$address = 'localhost';
$port = 4444; //Different port numbers produce same result

if (($sock = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) === false) 
{
    echo "socket_create() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
    exit();
}

 if (socket_bind($sock, $address, $port) === false) 
{
    echo "socket_bind() failed: reason: " . socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)) . "\n";
    exit();
}

...
```

This results in

> usr=root
>   Warning: socket_bind(): unable to bind address [98]: Address already in use in /var/www/nbr/socket.php on line 28 socket_bind() failed: reason: Address already in use

I've tried a number of things which give indications of what the problem may be, but not how to resolve it.  socket_getsockname produces garbage when I try to echo the address and port information, but if I change `AF_UNIX` to `AF_INET`, and add

```
$addr = ""; $pt = "";    
echo "Socket name ok: " . socket_getsockname($sock, &$addr, &$pt) . '<br/>';
echo $addr .    ", " . $pt . '<br/>';
```

the result is

> Socket name ok: 1
>
> 0.0.0.0, 0

So is address/port just never set properly somehow?  Also, subsequent `socket_get_option($sock, 0, SO_REUSEADDR)` fails with `AF_UNIX`, succeeds with `AF_INET` but I still get the address unavailable error.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: AF_UNIX is a unix local domain socket - basically a file somewhere on your machine. As such there's no "address" or "port", since it's a file. AF_INET means a TCP/IP socket, for which there IS a port/address.

Comment: @Marc A local domain socket is what I want--I didn't know it was a file.  Will editing it in some way help my issue, and if so you know where it is, or how I can find it?

Comment: If you just want to read from a socket that already exists, then just use the regular fopen/fread/fclose stuff, otherwise this other answer should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307692/simplest-way-to-open-and-use-a-socket-in-c

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`socket_bind` is used to bind a socket on the local machine. Binding a socket means *reserve a address/port* for a socket. You usually use it for a listener (server) not a client. In your case, since the server (Qt) is already started, then the address is already in use, so `socket_bind` will fail.

If you want to *connect to a socket*, use `socket_connect`:

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
if (!socket_connect($socket, 'localhost', 4444)) {
    die('failed');
}
```

If you want to connect to a local socket (i.e.: through a socket file, and not through TCP/UDP):

```
$socket = socket_create(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
if (!socket_connect($socket, '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock')) {
    die('failed');
}
```

Comment: Your method for TCP/IP sockets worked fine--thank you!  I'm now in the process of getting this to work for local sockets.

Answer (score 2):

First clear use port:

```
<?PHP
$port= 4444;
$cmd = explode("*", str_replace(array("/"), "*",
    str_replace(" ","",shell_exec("netstat -tulpn | grep :".$port))));
if (count($cmd)>1) {  //if found use port
    shell_exec("kill -9 " . $cmd[1]);
}
.
.
.
.code
```