# Segmentation Fault in C function

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am trying to develop a basic shell. For that shell I need a C function to parse a string. As i am new to C I tried to develop a basic function and it gives me a segmentation fault error. Please tell me what I am missing.

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>


void parse(char *msg);
int main()
{
    char *msg =  "This is a message";
    parse(msg);
}

void parse(char *msg){
    char *mm;
    mm = msg;

    char *tok;
    tok = strtok(mm," ");
    while(tok == NULL){
        tok = strtok(NULL," ");
            printf("%s \n",tok);
    }
}
```

Error Message (Runtime)

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: How many times you guys are going to ask this very same question **and** at the same time not RTFM? String literals are constants, there is **no friggin' way** you can modify their contents.

Comment: (For the exact same reason, **`const`** `char *msg = "foo";`

Comment: @H2CO3, Perhaps it is time to edit the C tag wiki similar questions to add questions related to [undefined behaviour](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4176328/undefined-behavior-and-sequence-points) and [sockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307692/simplest-way-to-open-and-use-a-socket-in-c) since they seem to be over-asked?

Comment: @AnishRam That's a constructive suggestion. (Unfortunately, people who ask these types of questions don't tend to read the tag wikis either.)

Comment: @H2CO3, Hmm. Good point. (Off to brainstorm new feature request :D)

Comment: @H2CO3: to be fair to the OP, that's not the only bug in their code that could lead to a segfault ;-)

Comment: @NPE: what else leads to a segfault?  I can see bugs that lead to no output appearing, but that's a very different problem from a segfault.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I meant the NULL pointer business in `parse()`. However, this would require the caller to supply a different input. In any case, see the smiley face.

Comment: @NPE Well, while I couldn't immediately grasp that, I'm sure there will be some other parts of the code which suffer from similar problems (but that's why the C-FAQ has been created, and in my opinion, this question is 1. lacks research effort, 2. (so) it's a dupe, 3. thusly it's not suited for Stack Overflow.)

Comment: @H2CO3: Oh, I am not arguing that this is a particularly good question. It definitely lacks research effort. That said, it is clear, complete and has nearly-working code, which makes it a better question than much of what I see asked here. Also, I suspect you might have overlooked the smiley face at the end of my other comment. :-)

Comment: @NPE Nope, don't worry ;-) And yes, you are right in that it basically comes with a SSCCE, and that's rare.

Answer (score 5):

`msg` points to a string literal, and you are attempting to modify it. In C, modifying string literals is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) (in practice, compilers often place them in read-only memory).

To fix, turn `msg` into an array:

```
int main()
{
    char msg[] =  "This is a message";
    parse(msg);
}
```

Also, there are a couple of issues with your `while` loop:

1) the condition is the wrong way round;
2) the second `strtok()` call should appear *after* the `printf()`.

```
void parse(char *msg){
    char *mm = msg;
    char *tok = strtok(mm, " ");
    while (tok) {
        printf("%s \n",tok);
        tok = strtok(NULL," ");
    }
}
```

Comment: @phresnel **The fact** that modifying them results in UB permits the compiler to place them in ROM. The original wording was fine too.

Comment: @H2CO3: That's exactly what I meant by the original wording, thanks. I've changed it as it seemed not clear enough.

Comment: @H2CO3: Or let's say, the wording was not totally unambiguous to at least one person ("what follows from what"). I removed my comment. +1 btw.

Answer (score 4):

You can't reliably modify a string literal; they are often readonly (and in your case, clearly are readonly).  An attempt to modify a string literal invokes undefined behaviour, which is always a Bad Thing™!

Use:

```
int main(void)
{
    char msg[] = "This is a message";
    parse(msg);
}
```

Comment: how did you write the trade mark symbol?can i write a superscript or subscript?i know its off topic but got curious.

Comment: @Koushik You can always just copy the character from somewhere like [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trademark_symbol). Also, for questions about things like formatting and such about Stack Overflow, there's http://meta.stackoverflow.com/.

Comment: @Koushik: On a Mac keyboard, Option 2.  Or use either the keyboard viewer or character viewer.  Elsewhere, there's usually a way, not always obvious.  The Unicode code point is U+2122; you may be able to do something with the Alt key and ... end up typing 2122.

Comment: @ajp15243 yeah thats one option but his response was quick and so dint think he would have copied from somewhere.:-)

Comment: I must admit, I am slightly jealous of that Option + 2 entry method for it.

Comment: @ajp15243 right?:-) me too.

Comment: Note you can also "fake" a <sup>TM-thingy</sup> using some of the allowed HTML. edit: Obviously, in comments it does not work.

Comment: Anyone want to make a question of it?  How to enter arbitrary Unicode characters on a Windows or Linux or Mac keyboard?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: It seems it hasn't been asked yet (i.e. it is not a first-result on google, yet). Take the opportunity, otherwise I might steal your idea and ask my first superuser question in the next hour :D

Comment: Be my guest — link to it when you've asked it.

Comment: @phresnel HTML sounds like a lot of work:-) it would be so cool to just get that in couple of keypress,if not for a keypress.

Comment: @Koushik: Though it consistently works accross operating systems, distros, and browsers.

Comment: @phresnel there is no denying of that fact.

Answer (score 2):

Your definition:

```
char *msg =  "This is a message";
```

makes `msg` as constant char string which cannot be modified. But `strtok` modifies it.

You may want to change it to

```
char *msg =  strdup("This is a message");
```

Don't forget to free the pointer after you are done.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps instead of

```
while(tok == NULL)
```

you meant

```
while(tok != NULL)
```

or just

```
while (tok) // <- because in C, conditions are always compared to 0
```

. However, what gives you the segmentation fault is that `strtok` modifies the passed string, which is why it takes a *non-const* pointer to `char` (see http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok). Therefore, because you are passing a pointer to a string literal, which are not modifiable, you receive a segmentation fault (which is your *luck*; this bug might also slip through QA and go production if you are unlucky).

Answer (score 1):

Go with it.........

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>


void parse(char *msg);
int main()
{
    char msg[] =  "This is a message";
    parse(msg);
}

void parse(char *msg){
    char *mm;
    mm = msg;

    char *tok;
    tok = strtok(mm," ");
    while(tok != NULL){
        printf("%s \n",tok);
    tok = strtok(NULL," ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is not helpful at all. My recommendation is to not post "Try This"-answers (see also my profile page).

Comment: Your edit doesn't make this any more helpful. How about adding some explanations?

Comment: I am not getting what clarification u want regarding this?

Comment: You gave the asker a complete solution. This may work now. But the askers possibly learns nothing from it for the future. There is a saying: "Give a man a fish, you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish, you feed him for life."

Answer (score 0):

how about change tok==NULL to tok!=NULL

Comment: But this answer was already redundant when you posted it, which is why Stack Overflow notifies you of new answers when pressing the submit-button.