# Socket won't work in c

Tags: sockets

```
#import <java.net.Socket>
#import <java.io.InputStream>
#import <java.io.OutputStream>

int main() {
 Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 80);
  InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
   }
```

I can not get simple socket opened it gives a compiler errors

Comment: this isn't C. where did you get this quote from?

Comment: this is for jni program to work

Comment: no its not. thats not how C works

Comment: I never thought this was possible, yet I see it in front of me. Cava: C + Java?

Comment: @usandfriends: More Cava++. The worst of two worlds ...

Comment: yes my friend showed me this code. is it because im missing something. jni is java native interface its how i write socket in c

Comment: @Alex: Although already stated by others: No, you **don't** <fullstop>. So now sit down, open a browser to your prefered search provider and search for "C socket programming". Possibly add "tutorial". Then read and learn. And if you have time, find new friends.

Comment: i just changed it and its still error and doesnt work

Comment: is this because c does not have support for socket. I need to access web internet port for my computer to test server

Comment: @Alex No, it has to do with the fact that your friend is trying to fuse C and Java. Tell your friend to re-learn C and/or Java....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks look you are trying to fuse C and Java.

Your example in pure Java:

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MyFirstSocket {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 80);
        InputStream in = socket.getInputStream();
        OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
    }
}
```

If you want to use sockets in C, see [Simplest Way To Open and Use a Socket in C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/307692/2006429).

Comment: thanks after digging through c codes i don't want to learn it. i know its a newer language than java but it is very bad with naming. i can hardly understand whats going on with the weird names. i will stick with the older languages like java and javascript for now.

Comment: C is much older than java and javascript... In fact, I'm pretty sure original implementations of java and javascript are written in C (or at least parts of them)